# How to name the folders created while installing the exe file that is published through oneclick installer

Tags: c#, oneclick, one-click-web-publishing

I am using oneclick installer available in the visualstudio  to deploy a desktop application.
After installing,the installation creates a folder in the user local appdata path (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5VOHNBL2.9EW\W5YA2RJW.64K\batc...exe_55e4bcf8b6e845f5_0001.0000_none_294f456f6b107c8a) 
How can i make sure that installation creates an readable folder names?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, ClickOnce wants to manage all that stuff itself.

If you prefer to install to a specific folder then don't deploy using ClickOnce. If you're going to use magic deployment technology then don't fight it, embrace the magic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there isn't much resources available on clickonce and customization seems to be difficult for beginners. Every online result for this question leads to me the same answer saying that it is not advised to modify the foldername.